# JLayeredPane in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, jlayeredpane

I am trying to put two components Jeditorpane and Jtextarea in Jlayeredpane. I am using Netbeans. I added jeditorpane and jtextarea in jlayeredpane and two buttons. When i click on button1 then it should show message "Hello world doing nice".

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextArea1.setText("");
    jTextArea1.setOpaque(true);
    jLayeredPane1.moveToFront(jEditorPane1);
    jEditorPane1.setText("Hello world doing nice");
}
```

and when click on button2 then it should show message "Hello world not doing good".

```
 private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jEditorPane1.setText("");
    jEditorPane1.setOpaque(true);
    jLayeredPane1.moveToFront(jTextArea1);
    jTextArea1.setText("Hello world not doing good");
}
```

But when i click on button1 then it shows message "Hello world doing nice" but when i click on button2 then it does not shows message "Hello world not doing good" as it should move the component to front. Could some one please tell me how to solve this. Here is source code which is partially generated by netbeans and partially written by me.
Thank you.

```
public class test extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form test */
public test() {
    initComponents();
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jLayeredPane1 = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jEditorPane1 = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLayeredPane1.add(jTextArea1);// i added this code using custom code property
    jLayeredPane1.add(jEditorPane1); //i added this code using custom code property 

    jEditorPane1.setText("");//i added this code using custom code property
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jEditorPane1);

    jScrollPane1.setBounds(0, 0, 480, 200);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.setText("");//i added this code using custom code property of netbeans
    jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    jScrollPane2.setBounds(0, 0, 480, 200);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 505, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(143, 143, 143)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
            .addContainerGap(68, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(42, 42, 42)
            .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 228, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(33, 33, 33)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addContainerGap(43, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jTextArea1.setText("");
    jTextArea1.setOpaque(true);
    jLayeredPane1.moveToFront(jEditorPane1);
    jEditorPane1.setText("Hello world doing nice");
}

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    jEditorPane1.setText("");
    jEditorPane1.setOpaque(true);
    jLayeredPane1.moveToFront(jTextArea1);
    jTextArea1.setText("Hello world not doing good");
}

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new test().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JEditorPane jEditorPane1;
private javax.swing.JLayeredPane jLayeredPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration
  }
```

Comment: Here is simplified version of my question. I want to overlap two swing components , jeditorpane and jtextarea.With particular event only jeditorpane's contents should be visible and with other events jtextarea's contents should be visible. Its like at one particular time , we have only one component is visible and not other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be using [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead.